# Facebook Android native key fail

Tags: android, facebook

When I try to implement [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect) in my Android application, I get the following error.

> Login failed:
>   invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key
>   "7dje38/jMXoU9Lezug4nzmZfFUg" does not match the allowed keys
>   specified in your application settings. Check your application
>   settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your key is: 7dje38/jMXoU9Lezug4nzmZfFUg.

Now copy this key and open [this URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig). And paste this key in the native Android application which is mark with a green border.

[image]

Comment: Did you implemented SSO in your Application?

Comment: Hey this is sample Application image SSo ... provide by fb in developer account.

Comment: How can I get my key in another way?